# How to set TextFormField to use primary color(on focus) in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-theme

I need to change label and border's default color to use the primary color on focus, and i've already tried InputDecorationTheme, but it doesn't work well with the label. I realize that the TextField uses accent color.

[The screen;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/goqs3.png)
and theme:

```dart
final ThemeData darkTheme = ThemeData(
    primaryColor: Colors.blueAccent[400],
    accentColor: Colors.pinkAccent[400],
    brightness: Brightness.dark,
    backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
    inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
        fillColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.1),
        filled: true,
    ),
);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the style in your TextFormField like:

```
style: TextStyle(
   color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor
),
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to change the outline and label's color on focus, I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

**utils.dart**

```
class AvailableFonts {
  static const primaryFont = "Quicksand";
  static const primaryFontSize = 14.0;
}
```

**theme.dart**

place it in `lib` folder as `main`

```
ThemeData buildThemeData() {
  final baseTheme = ThemeData(fontFamily: AvailableFonts.primaryFont);

 return baseTheme.copyWith(
   primaryColor: primaryColor,
   primaryColorDark: primaryDark,
   primaryColorLight: primaryLight,
   accentColor: secondaryColor,
);}
```

And, where you define your colours

**colours.dart**

```
const primaryColor = Colors.red;
const primaryLight = const Color(0xFFB71C1C);
const primaryDark = const Color(0xFFFF9F59);
const secondaryColor = Colors.white;
```

There after, you can simply use as an example bellow:

`color: primaryColor,`

Comment: It works, but I need to change the outline and label's color on focus, I'll edit my question, thank u.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way to call color:

```
focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                          color: ThemeData()
                              .inputDecorationTheme
                              .focusedBorder?.borderSide
                              .color ??
                              Colors.pink),
                    )
```